# Unable to initialize Fingerprint Sensor using Validity - Unexpected TLS Version 4.0

Tags: fingerprint-reader

when i try to run the initializer from https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint, i get the following error(Ive tried looking around but have not see anyone with this issue):

Specs: Lenovo T460S, Ubuntu 20.10 Fresh install/ (BIOS Fingerprint is enabled)

```
Found device <DEVICE ID 138a:0090 on Bus 001 Address 004>
Downloading https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1cgn08w.exe to extract 6_07f_Lenovo.xpfwext
Extracting "Synaptics Metallica MOH Touch Fingerprint Reader Driver" - setup data version 5.5.7
 - "app/WBF_Drivers/6_07f_Lenovo.xpfwext"
Done.
Found firmware at /tmp/tmpfnxinnoy/app/WBF_Drivers/6_07f_Lenovo.xpfwext
The device will be now reset to factory and associated to the current laptop.
Press Enter to continue (or Ctrl+C to cancel)...
Opening device 0x90
Factory reset...
Sleeping...
Try 1 failed with error: Failed: 0404
Sleeping...
Try 2 failed with error: Failed: 0404
Sleeping...
Try 3 failed with error: Failed: 0404
Device didn't reply in time...
Factory reset failed with Failed: 0404, this should not happen, but we can ignore it, if pairing works...
Sleeping...
Pairing the sensor with device 20FAS2SR01
Opening device 0x90
Initializing flash...
Detected Flash IC: W25Q80B, 1048576 bytes
Sleeping...
Try 1 failed with error: Failed: 04af
Opening device 0x90
Initializing flash...
Sleeping...
Try 2 failed with error: Unexpected TLS version 4 0
Opening device 0x90
Initializing flash...
Sleeping...
Try 3 failed with error: Unexpected TLS version 4 0
Opening device 0x90
Initializing flash...
Sleeping...
Try 4 failed with error: Unexpected TLS version 4 0
Opening device 0x90
Initializing flash...
Sleeping...
Try 5 failed with error: Unexpected TLS version 4 0
Device didn't reply in time...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/validity-sensors-tools.py", line 339, in <module>
    vfs_tools.initialize(fwpath, args.calibration_data)
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/validity-sensors-tools.py", line 249, in initialize
    self.pair(fwpath, calib_data)
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/validity-sensors-tools.py", line 220, in pair
    self.retry_command(init_flash_command, max_retries=5)
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/validity-sensors-tools.py", line 112, in retry_command
    raise(err)
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/validity-sensors-tools.py", line 103, in retry_command
    command()
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/validity-sensors-tools.py", line 219, in init_flash_command
    init_flash()
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/proto9x/init_flash.py", line 97, in init_flash
    partition_flash(flash_layout_hardcoded, client_public)
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/proto9x/init_flash.py", line 70, in partition_flash
    info = get_flash_info()
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/proto9x/flash.py", line 28, in get_flash_info
    rsp=tls.cmd(unhex('3e'))
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/proto9x/tls.py", line 104, in cmd
    rsp=self.app(cmd)
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/proto9x/tls.py", line 138, in app
    return self.parse_tls_response(self.usb.cmd(self.make_app_data(b)))
  File "/snap/validity-sensors-tools/65/vfs-tools/proto9x/tls.py", line 336, in parse_tls_response
    raise Exception('Unexpected TLS version %d %d' % (mj, mn))
Exception: Unexpected TLS version 4 0
```

Comment: If this is a bug, perhaps it would make more sense to [open an Issue with the developer](https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint/issues) rather than post it here 

Comment: not sure if its a bug or something in my BIOS that's messing it up

Comment: That's fine, but neither are something that people on this site can particularly help with. We didn't write the code in the GitHub repository you're linking to. Most people here are enthusiastic volunteers and not at all affiliated with Canonical. And, if it's a BIOS issue, this is something that would be better answered by Lenovo 

Comment: Thanks! I was trying my luck in hopes someone may of seen this issue. Thanks again!